# Quickly reload nix expression in nix-shell?

Tags: nixos, nix

When I run nix-shell

`nix-shell ~/dev/nixpkgs -A pythonPackages.some-package`

and then edit phases of `pythonPackages.some-package`, how to reload `nix-shell` environment with new changes?

Quit `nix-shell` and rerun is one option, but are there alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No other simple options, sorry. I can only think of rewriting nix-shell to accomplish what you want. Probably it's not even that hard. Reparse the expression, cleanup the env and refill the env.

Answer (score 2):

New project `lorri` is built exactly to support this feature. It requires `shell.nix` file to be present and depends on `direnv`.

https://github.com/target/lorri